# Browser render engine: How ReactJS is instructing render engine for the DOM part update?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I understood that ReactJS uses Virtual DOM to diff to find the updated DOM node and re-render only the part of DOM node, instead of updating all the DOM nodes.
Usually browser render engine re-paints all the DOM nodes and i am wondering how ReactJS instructs render engine to update only particular node..!

Comment: Please share your code

Answer (score 0):

Repaints happens only to the elements that are currently on screen. Reflows happen only to elements that changed (or are affected by changes).

React's "Virtual DOM" simply aims to reduce the amount of changes in the browser DOM, nothing more. I does not (cannot) instruct the browser to (re)render individual nodes.